# Convert month name to numeric string

Tags: java

This code converts a 3-letter English month abbreviation to its numeric equivalent (as a string).

```java
public static String numericMonth(String monthInFull) {
  monthInFull = monthInFull.toUpperCase();
  if (monthInFull.equals("JAN")) { return "01"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("FEB")) { return "02"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("MAR")) { return "03"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("APR")) { return "04"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("MAY")) { return "05"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("JUN")) { return "06"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("JUL")) { return "07"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("AUG")) { return "08"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("SEP")) { return "09"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("OCT")) { return "10"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("NOV")) { return "11"; }
  if (monthInFull.equals("DEC")) { return "12"; }
  return "";
}
```

Is it possible to create an array (or Enum?) listing the month names and their respective index (or index + 1) and avoid this excess of `if`?

Comment: Using a `switch` statement would remove much of the repetition in your code.  Whether or not using an `enum` here is beneficial or appropriate would require more context for how/where this code is being used.

Comment: (`monthInFull` for three-letter abbrev.s is kind of odd. That's not a *static String*, but a *static `String` **method***.) Please mention that run time is absolutely no concern.

Comment: The new _switch expression_: `return switch (monthFull.toUpperCase()) { case "JAN" => "01"; case "FEB" => "02"; ... };}`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/enum.html is a possible startup point.

Answer (score 3):

Some improvement ideas:

1. You could consider using `java.time` api, however to use `DateTimeFormatter` you'd have to use builder, quite heavily configure it (as it would require defaults for year and day, not to mention its case sensitive) and `Month` class does not seem to offer anything to help here - the benefit of this approach would be that you don't have to maintain localized list of months (but would end up with a date from which month would have to be extracted - additional step, unless there is some other way that I don't see)
2. For current solution you can use map (like `Map.of("JAN", 1, "FEB", 2...`) and instead of repeating `if` have one `get` (or `getOrDefault` if you want to return default value, but...)
3. I'd propose to throw exception instead of returning empty string for month out of bounds - I am not sure of exact use case but I'd prefer to know when something unexpected is happening in my code rather than continue execution (fail fast)
4. Consider using `String.format("%02d", parsedMonthNumber)` instead manually prepending zeros to numbers - not that it is important in any way (can be even considered unnecessary complication) but this way you separate a little your "app logic" (parsing month number) from "display logic" (or are better of if such separation was ever needed - benefit of such separation is that you can use integer for number instead of string)

Edit: ad. 1 you *could* also use `Month.values()` check if name contains your raw month string and `getValue` - limiting yourself to english representations of months... but it kinda feels a little off